# Is there a universally accepted pattern for the placement of floating actions on websites based on their directionality?

Tags: floating-action-button

Many websites have floating actions, like adding a new task, talking to a support agent, a direct-call button for marketing, etc.

For the LTR languages, what I have seen is that they put it on the lower-right side of the screen.

However, I asked GPT for RTL languages, and it said it's better to put it on the lower-left side.

Yet I checked some instances and discovered that they put it on the lower-right side.

Is there a universally recommended pattern for this?

Comment: I don't think it's because of a pattern, but because these are usually third party services and they have coded it this way for all users, hence users have no choice. At least I have never seen an option for RTL

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take a step back here: *Why* are FABs positioned where they are? The [Material guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/floating-action-button/guidelines) only say

> The FAB can be aligned left, center, or right. It can be positioned above the navigation bar, or nested within the bar.

so it's not a Google-given law or anything.

No, the reason for their usual right-handed-ness is twofold:

For one, people are generally thought of as right-handed, so putting the FAB in the bottom right corner makes the button more easily accessible in one-handed operations.

For another, there's generally fewer important information getting obscured by the FAB. For example:

[image: FAB in an email client]
If the FAB was on the other side here, it'd obscure sender and title of the email, while on the other side it only obscures the date. Importantly, if your screen is large enough, Google recommends to put the thing into a navigation bar instead as that's the best place where it remains extremely prominent without obscuring any information.

[image: MD3 example suggesting top-right placement, underneath the hamburger menu]

So, what does that mean for RTL layouts?

It means you now have to **weigh the usefulness of the button not obscuring content against the button being further away from the natural hand position** - assuming people are right-handed. If this tradeoff is worth it depends on your exact app. I recommend user-testing this.

---

Let's come back to your initial observation:

> Many websites have floating actions, like adding a new task, talking to a support agent, a direct-call button for marketing, etc.

One of these is not like the others. The point of a FAB in principle is to make the most relevant action very prominent and accessible. In an email program, that's writing a new mail, in a task list program, it's adding a task.

The support agent buttons, the marketing call buttons, the obnoxious chat bots - those aren't FABs, they don't serve the same purpose as a FAB. Rather, they act as an alternative entry method - you either browse their website, or you talk to the bot/marketing person. As far as I can tell, it's somewhat rare that people switch from one to the other and back, unless explicitly prompted to do so by the website.

**To those chatbot-"FABs", the considerations of a regular FAB don't really apply**, if the button is used, it's not going to be with the same per-user frequency as the primary action of a productivity app. Therefore, they can be placed wherever they interfere with the content the least.